# Whitelisting session files with rkhunter

Tags: rkhunter

I am running a webserver and am saving PHP sessions to /dev/shm -- rkhunter is flagging the session files:

> Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
>
> > /dev/shm/sess_eir6fi80ld0bs3ejsjvgkjiuc4: ASCII text, with no line terminators
> >       /dev/shm/sess_73v97tg98bd9jckbiovruclhb5: ASCII text, with no line terminators
> >       /dev/shm/sess_f1aglts90oqksrc82eg4lc5i27: ASCII text, with no line terminators
> >       /dev/shm/sess_a5hot1l1eehonnqa5i025mtu10: ASCII text, with no line terminators

I have tried the following ALLOWDEVFILE directives in /etc/rkhunter.conf, but none of them seem to work:

> ALLOWDEVFILE=/dev/shm/sess_*
>
> ALLOWDEVFILE="/dev/shm/sess_*"

rkhunter still flags all sess_* files. Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `EXISTWHITELIST` directive rather than `ALLOWDEVFILE`, which is for whitelisting files in `/dev`.

Comment: Using EXISTWHITELIST=/dev/shm/sess_* did not help and also not with quotes. I have rkhunter v1.3.6 on a Debian Squeeze box.